# Virtuemart 2 Multilanguage manufacturers double

Tags: php, mysql, joomla2.5, virtuemart

We use Virtuemart on a website with the following issue. We use multilanguage on the website, but on the english version the manufacturers show both dutch and english links to the manufacturers.

Below is the code we use:

```
<?php
/**
*
* Description
*
* @package  VirtueMart
* @subpackage Manufacturer
* @author Kohl Patrick, Eugen Stranz
* @link http://www.virtuemart.net
* @copyright Copyright (c) 2004 - 2010 VirtueMart Team. All rights reserved.
* @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
* VirtueMart is free software. This version may have been modified pursuant
* to the GNU General Public License, and as distributed it includes or
* is derivative of works licensed under the GNU General Public License or
* other free or open source software licenses.
* @version $Id: default.php 2701 2011-02-11 15:16:49Z impleri $
*/

// Check to ensure this file is included in Joomla!
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

// Category and Columns Counter
$iColumn = 1;
$iManufacturer = 1;

// Calculating Categories Per Row
$manufacturerPerRow = 3;
if ($manufacturerPerRow != 1) {
    $manufacturerCellWidth = ' width'.floor ( 100 / $manufacturerPerRow );
} else {
    $manufacturerCellWidth = '';
}

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$page_title = $doc->getTitle();
// Lets output the categories, if there are some
if (!empty($this->manufacturers)) { ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
function equalHeight(group) {
   tallest = 0;
   group.each(function() {
      thisHeight = jQuery(this).height();
      if(thisHeight > tallest) {
         tallest = thisHeight;
      }
   });
   group.height(tallest);
}
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   equalHeight(jQuery(".sameheight"));
});
</script>

<div class="manufacturer-view-default category-view">
    <div class="bp_page_head_bar_cat">
    <h2><?php echo $page_title ?></h2>
    </div>

    <?php // Start the Output
    foreach ( $this->manufacturers as $manufacturer ) { ?>
    <!--
    <pre>
    <?php print_r($manufacturer); ?>
    </pre>
    -->
    <?php
        // Show the horizontal seperator
        if ($iColumn == 1 && $iManufacturer > $manufacturerPerRow) { ?>
            <div class="horizontal-separator"></div>
      <?php }

        // this is an indicator wether a row needs to be opened or not
        if ($iColumn == 1) { ?>
        <div class="row">
        <?php }

        // Manufacturer Elements
        $manufacturerURL = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&virtuemart_manufacturer_id=' . $manufacturer->virtuemart_manufacturer_id);
        $manufacturerIncludedProductsURL = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&virtuemart_manufacturer_id=' . $manufacturer->virtuemart_manufacturer_id);
        $manufacturerImage = $manufacturer->images[0]->displayMediaFull("",false);

        // Show Category ?>
        <div class="manufacturer category floatleft<?php echo $manufacturerCellWidth ?>">
            <div class="FWcategorybox sameheight">
                <center>
                    <a id="FWcategorynameImage" alias="<?php echo $manufacturer->mf_name; ?>" title="<?php echo $manufacturer->mf_name; ?>" href="<?php echo $manufacturerURL; ?>"><?php echo $manufacturerImage;?></a>
                </center>
                    <a id="FWcategorynamelink" title="<?php echo $manufacturer->mf_name; ?>" href="<?php echo $manufacturerURL; ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer->mf_name; ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        $iManufacturer ++;

        // Do we need to close the current row now?
        if ($iColumn == $manufacturerPerRow) {
            echo '<div class="clear"></div></div>';
            $iColumn = 1;
        } else {
            $iColumn ++;
        }
    }

    // Do we need a final closing row tag?
    if ($iColumn != 1) { ?>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>

</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [SO] and paste question text at [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)).

Answer (score 0):

I found it. After debugging de database I found there were some wrong ID's. So I've updated the wrong ID's with the correct ones.